# Is there a function or extension that shows one view in a case containing the content of the Summary and Details fields of all activities

Tags: civicase, user-experience

We are seeking to show, preferably in the management of a case not as a separate report, a list of the Summary and Details fields of all activities in a case. The goal is to promote the use of cases. Currently, our user resistance focuses on the lack of a view where all of the text written by self or others on the case is tucked away inside each activity and not visible as one cohesive narrative. Ideally, the texts could be edited from this new view. The rows in the view would probably be in chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

The print report link on manage case might satisfy the need to see a comprehensive list in a view. It's not editable though.

Comment: Hi Demerit, my users could use this but they come from an Excel background where they had rapid response and immediate visibility of "just what they needed" (albeit that it was only visible to them, was single user and didn't provide effective handover from one part time staff member to the next). They don't yet see that the use of CiviCase is beneficial because of its engagement with a corporate wide view. That is the hurdle that I am trying to overcome. I really appreciate your rapid reply. Thx, Rob